# Double while loop keeps running after breaking line

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to write a function that crops certain shapes from a 2D numpy array. I've only finished half the code yet, right now it's supposed to strip vertical lines of data that contain a shape, but it keeps throwing errors at me. Here's the code thus far:

```py
def shapes(array, thresh):
    shapes = {}
    thresharray = array
    thresharray[thresharray  < thresh] = 0
    thresharray[thresharray >= thresh] = 1
    count  = 0
    outcheck = False
    while outcheck == False:
        incheck = False
        ind     = False
        while incheck == False:
            shape = np.zeros((thresharray.shape[0], 1))
            for i in range(thresharray.shape[1]):
                if   all(thresharray[:, [i]] == 0):
                    print(shape.shape)
                    if ind ==  True:
                        shape = np.delete(shape, 0, 1)
                        shapes[count] = shape
                        incheck = True
                    if i   == range(thresharray.shape[1])[-1]:
                        outcheck = True
                elif any(thresharray[:, [i]]  > 0):
                    shape = np.hstack((shape, thresharray[:, [i]]))
                    thresharray[:, [i]] = 0
                    print(shape.shape)
                    if ind == False:
                        ind = True
                    if i   == range(thresharray.shape[1])[-1]:
                        outcheck = True
    return shapes
```

It does stack the arrays correctly, but then when it reaches the `incheck = True` part it just keeps going for some reason and erases the strip one line at a time instead of resetting the `shape`. Here's the console output:

```py
(121, 1)
(121, 1)
(121, 2)
(121, 3)
(121, 4)
(121, 5)
(121, 6)
(121, 7)
(121, 8)
(121, 9)
(121, 10)
(121, 11)
(121, 12)
(121, 13)
(121, 14)
(121, 15)
(121, 15)
(121, 14)
(121, 13)
(121, 12)
(121, 11)
(121, 10)
(121, 9)
(121, 8)
(121, 7)
(121, 6)
(121, 5)
(121, 4)
(121, 3)
(121, 2)
(121, 1)
(121, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kit/Desktop/Python/407/407.py", line 162, in <module>
    print(len(shapes(radinterp, 0.7)))
  File "/home/kit/Desktop/Python/407/407.py", line 33, in shapes
    shape = np.delete(shape, 0, 1)
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4376, in delete
    "size %i" % (obj, axis, N))
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0
```

Comment: `incheck` and `outcheck` only control the `while` loops. Setting them doesn't break out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `break` out of the `for` loop after you set `incheck = True`

Comment: hmm, when I put a `break` statement after the `incheck = True` it just gets stuck in an endless loop printing the same `shape.shape`. What am I not seeing?

Comment: @AndriiKozytskyi because `outcheck` still equals `False`. Delete the `break` you aadded after your last `elif` statement put `if outcheck == True and incheck == true break`